# DB2 Conection issue using SSL. Protocol specific error code(s): "420", SQLSTATE=08001

Tags: python, ssl, db2

I am not able to make the SSL connection to a DB2 database using Python. I have the server certificate; the arm file (`DigiCertGlobalRootCA.arm`). I can make the SSL connection using Dbeaver and JDBC driver using the `db2jcc4.jar` file but I really need the Python connection. Appreciate any hints.

I am using `port 31246` becuase this is a private cloud instance.

running `Python -V`, I get `Python 3.7.0`

running `db2level`, I get

```
DB21085I  Instance DB2 uses 64 bits and DB2 code release SQL09074 with
level identifier 08050107.
Informational tokens are DB2 v9.7.400.501, s110330, IP23238, and Fix Pack
4.
Product is installed at C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB with DB2 Copy Name DB2COPY1.
```

My OS is Windows 10 Enterprise.

My code is not running on a Container.

I am using the same Hostname, port, uid, pass for the Dbeaver connection.

Here is the connection string that I am using: `String = "database=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=" + "hostname" + ";PORT=" + "31246" + ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=" + "userid" + ";PWD=" + "MyPass" + ";SECURITY=ssl;"+"SSLServerCertificate=C:/SSL/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.arm;"`

Below is the error I am getting:

```
SQL30081N A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol
being used: "SSL". Communication API being used: "SOCKETS". Location where
the error was detected: "". Communication function detecting the error:
"sqlccSSLSocketSetup". Protocol specific error code(s): "420", "", "".
SQLSTATE=08001
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify with answers to these questions below.  (don't add facts in comments because comments are not searchable). Why are you using port 31246 (is this a private cloud instance?), a shared instance might use port 50001 ?  What's the text output of `python -V`. Which Db2 driver are you using? (what's the text output of `db2level` command). Which Windows-version and edition?  Is it running in a container?  Is the working dbeaver connection from the same Windows hostname , to the same database, with the same port-number and same certificate?

Comment: Looks like your workstation has an antique Db2 driver on the PATH, which is getting used instead of the default clidriver.   If you don't need that antique v9.7 driver then uninstall it completely and open a new CMD window to verify it is no longer on the PATH and that variables IBM_DB_HOME and IBM_DB_DIR and IBM_DB_LIB are unset .  Then `pip uninstall ibm_db` and `pip install ibm_db`. This will cause clidriver to auto install with ibm_db. Retry the connection.